# Garbage Value in Calloc in the last memory block

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
main()
{
  int *p;
  p = calloc(5,2);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%d ",*(p+i));
  }
}
```

Why is the output giving a garbage value in the last memory block when calloc sets the memory of all the blocks by default to zero?

Comment: Likely the size of an integer is not 2 bytes on your system.

Comment: the parameters to `calloc()` are 1) the count of items you want and 2) the size of each item.   If the `sizeof(int)` is not 2 (in todays systems it is usually 4) then accessing (as the call to `printf()` will do) anything beyond the first (in the current scenario) 10 bytes is: 1) going to return garbage 2) undefined behavior that can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `calloc(5, sizeof(int))`. You allocated 5 x 2 bytes, but int is usually 4 bytes large. Using sizeof() is a good practice due to portability.

Comment: The only situation, where you don't need `sizeof` is with `char` and it's derived data types (like `const signed char` or `volatile unsigned char` and the like),